# add subitems in listview in android

Tags: android

I have a listvew and I add subitem into the listview like this code

```
public class MyCustomListView extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
ListView lv;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.custom_list_view);
    lv=(ListView) this.findViewById(R.id.lvvv);      
  
    SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this,list, R.layout.custom_row_view,new String[] {"pen","color"},
            new int[] {R.id.text1, R.id.text3}
            );
    populateList(); 
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
} 
  
static final ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> list = 
    new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>(); 

private void populateList() {
    HashMap<String,String> temp = new HashMap<String,String>();
    temp.put("pen","MONT Blanc");       
    temp.put("color", "Black");
    list.add(temp);
    
    HashMap<String,String> temp1 = new HashMap<String,String>();
    temp1.put("pen","Gucci");
    temp1.put("color", "Red");
    list.add(temp1);
    
    HashMap<String,String> temp2 = new HashMap<String,String>();
    temp2.put("pen","Parker");
    temp2.put("color", "Blue");
    

}
```

}

but in the color key, if I have a lot of colors for a pen, and I want to arrange the colors into a list and this color list is under the pen.

ex:

-pen: Parker.

+color: blue.

+color: red.

how should I do that? please help me!
thank alot.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use an ExpanadableListView. Check out this - 
[ExpanadaleListView Tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/)